# What is a more optimal method for performing this Pandas Computation

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, bigdata, data-mining

I am trying to build a useable NLP corpus but getting bottlenecked by how long the program takes (200 hours). With so much data I know that optimizing my code even a little bit will net me huge time savings down the road, so I wanted to post this code and ask for some advice on speeding it up. I added a parameter to load the dataset if I have already made it, resulting in much faster times afterward, and tested on a small portion of the dataset, not the whole thing. When generating the tables, kwargs expects a size parameter and for loading it expects two file directory parameters. The features "full_text" is the raw full text of an academic article and "full_text_cleaned" has had the text set to lowercase and punctuation stripped. I can also provide how I created this dataset if requested.

Sample Corpus: 29000 entries

| paper_id | title | abstract | full_text | full_text_cleaned |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | string | string | string | string |

Relevant code

```py
class Doc_Finder():
    def __init__(self, corpus_file):
        self.corpus = pd.read_csv(corpus_file)
        self.corpus_dir = corpus_file

    def make_keywords(self, save=False, load=False, **kwargs):
        if save and load:
            raise Exception("Invalid Parameters")
        if save:
            self.keyword_index = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','keyword'])
            total = kwargs['size']
            self.keyword_map = []
            for _, row in tqdm(self.corpus.head(total).iterrows(), total=total):
                s = []
                for i in str(row['full_text_cleaned']).split(' '): 
                    if i not in s and not i.isnumeric() and i not in stopwords.words('english') and i.isalnum() and not isHyperlink(i):
                        s.append(i)
                        if i not in self.keyword_map:
                            self.keyword_map.append(i)
                for i in s:
                    self.keyword_index.loc[len(self.keyword_index.index)] = [row['paper_id'], i]
            
            if save:
                idx_dir = './keyword_index_' + str(total) + '.csv'
                self.keyword_index.to_csv(idx_dir, index=False)
                tempdf = pd.DataFrame(data=self.keyword_map, columns=['keyword'], dtype=str)
                map_dir = './keyword_map_' + str(total) + '.csv'
                tempdf.to_csv(map_dir, index=False)
        elif load:
            self.keyword_index = pd.read_csv(kwargs['index_dir'])
            self.keyword_map = pd.read_csv(kwargs['map_dir'])['keyword'].tolist()
```

I run the code using this snippet

```py
doc_finder = Doc_Finder(sample_corpus)
doc_finder.make_keywords(save=True, size=len(doc_finder.corpus['paper_id']))
```

The result is two csvs:

The keyword index which has a paper_id and keyword pair. Listing each keyword and each paper.

| paper_id | keyword |
| --- | --- |
| 00033d5a12240a8684cfe943954132b43434cf48 | extraction |
| 00033d5a12240a8684cfe943954132b43434cf48 | expected |

Then the set of all keywords from all the documents. This is in an attempt to make the document retrieval I will be doing after this faster, as I can match against the set of keywords and then query all the papers that have those keywords in the index table.

Keyword list

| keyword |
| --- |
| expected |
| ... |

I recognize that an SQL table of some kind would probably be a better solution, but I am limited to my local machine and do not know SQL very well. I also found a library called Dask but I think I would need to rethink how I perform this creation process since not all of the techniques would transfer. I am a little out of my comfort zone but this has been a rewarding experience.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [codereview.se]. However be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) and their [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting.

Comment: @Nick I tried before posting here but it said "You can only post a question once every 40 minutes" and I haven't posted a question there since 2019

Comment: Regarding the computation time, I think this reach the limit of what Python can do. The first thing to do is to check if one specific function is particularly more expensive than others using *profiling*. Currently, it is hard to help you since the code is not fully reproducible and we do not have detailed profiling information.

Comment: I think there are two main options here (unless you find a big bottleneck easy to fix in one function). The first is to parallelize the code using multiprocessing. This means you should refactor the code so to separate the fully compute-bound part which can be easily parallelized from the rest. Since you are working on strings and CPython has a cumbersome GIL preventing any speed-up using multithreading, the only solution to parallelize the code is to use multiple processes. That being said,  this require possibly expensive data transfer that may be more expensive than the computation...

Comment: The alternative solution is just not to use Python, at least, for the hottest computing part (this means you should profile your code anyway). Cython can help to spot some expensive parts and progressively switch to a native language like C or C++. However, this might be simpler, faster and more flexible to use a native language for all the computation except if this code is a part of a bigger application. At least, you will not be limited by the CPython for the parallelism, nor unicode string which can be expensive, nor the interpreter which is very slow.

Comment: I got it down from 200hours to 8 seconds by using actual vectorized operations and apply function switch to a Dask dataframe also saved me a bunch of time